# Do the Power Rangers’ 'Zord machines' ever cause collateral damage when it's morphin' time?

Tags: power-rangers

Like when each Power Ranger has their different "big robot Zord suit", the mega robots they use to fight the bad guys, *when they activate and travel from wherever, does collateral damage occur during travel?*

I mean especially in the television series *[Power Rangers Beast Morphers](https://powerrangers.fandom.com/wiki/Power_Rangers_Beast_Morphers)* show but also in the other Power Ranger series'.

Comment: Like when each power ranger has their different big robot suit (sorry I forget what) their called, but the mega robots they use to fight the bad guys, when they activate and travel from wherever, does collateral damage occur during travel and or during battle?

Comment: I've tried to clear up what you're asking with an edit. Feel free to [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/214947/edit) further if you want to clarify.

Comment: I've only seen a handful of Power Rangers episodes, but I've noticed their Zords always seem to activate in open areas or forests where there's no real danger of collateral damage. Of course, there's *hundreds* of Power Rangers episodes, so I don't feel confident enough to make that an answer.

Comment: They had individual Zords (robots), 1 per ranger and they could be brought together to form the Megazord. Some seasons the Megazord could be combined with a kinda "carrier" Zord to form the Ultrazord

Comment: Are you interested in just the TV series, or also in the *Power Rangers* (2017) film? In the film, Zords damage roads when they run. I'll post an answer with screenshots if you like.

Answer (score 1):

**We don't know**.

During the megazord battles even though they are in a city, there appears to be no one at all walking around, even though straight after each battle there are several.